# .gitignore file is not generated automatically

Tags: node.js, git, ubuntu, github

I initialized an empty git repository with `git init` and it's making only a .git folder. It's not making .gitignore itself. When I tried making a .gitignore file and then wrote `\node_modules`, it is not ignoring the node_modules folder. I am working with Linux OS on the NodeJs application and was pushing the code on GitHub.

Comment: 1. Why would it? 2. How about `node_modules/`?

Comment: I guess .gitignore is automatically generated?

Comment: Did you revisit that guess when the evidence suggested otherwise?

Comment: Try generating a `.gitignore` via https://www.gitignore.io/ - you'll need to commit it to your repo first before it will start ignoring files correctly.

Comment: @Manangoel **Why** do you "guess" that `.gitignore` is automatically generated? It is not.

Comment: Some IDEs will generate a `.gitignore` based on project type

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't get generated automatically. You need to first commit it in the repo and use "node_module/" in your .gitignore file.

```
$ cat .gitignore 
node_modules/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this as follows.

- Do `git init`
- Add `.gitignore` file
- Add file path or folder path you
  want to avoid
- Commit as `Git ignore file added` or something.
- Push to repository

After then if it's not working, 
`Clone it to another folder`. It will work, sure.